# Add svg icon in primeng button

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to add a .svg image instead of icon in primeng buttons, I want to display text on left side of the button and svg image on right corner in the same button.

I can achieve the same using prime icons with the below code, but i should achieve the same using svg image instead of that icon.

```
<button class="p-col-9 font_13" pButton iconPos="right" label="Hello!!" icon="fa fa-star">
</button>
```

Have already tried the below code, it shows up the image but breaks the whole UI and becomes unresponsive.

```
<button class="p-col-9 font_13" pButton label="{{floor.floor}}">
 <img src="../assets/icons/Right_Chevron.svg">
</button>
```

Answer (score -5):

Use fonts better.
Transform svg icons to font, use https://icomoon.io  for example.
Then just use your custom css-class.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and isn't good advice. Icon fonts aren't great for performance, and can be a real pain to maintain a custom pack as icons need updating.